# Kubernetes Deployment postStart error ResourceExhausted

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes, amazon-eks

I'm trying to run PostgreSQL in kubernetes with pre-defined tables, views and data. I've used the pod lifecycle postStart to execute the *.sql for creating tables, views and data

```
      lifecycle:
        postStart:
          exec:
            command: ["/bin/sh", "-c", "/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sh"]
```

The init.sh contains the psql command to execute the creation of tables, views and records as shown below

```
#!/bin/bash
database="sample"
psql -h localhost -U admin -d $database -a -f /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init_tables_01.sql
psql -h localhost -U admin -d $database -a -f /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init_views_02.sql
psql -h localhost -U admin -d $database -a -f /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init_data_03.sql
psql -h localhost -U admin -d $database -a -f /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init_data_04.sql
```

The tables and views were successfully created but during the record insertion I've encountered the below error.

```
Events:
Type     Reason               Age                From               Message
----     ------               ----               ----               -------
Normal   Scheduled            57s                default-scheduler  Successfully assigned app/app-postgres-5449b65999-pmlgb to ip-*.ec2.internal
Normal   Pulled               55s                kubelet            Successfully pulled image "*******.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/postgres:1.0.1" in
Normal   Pulled               40s                kubelet            Successfully pulled image "*******.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/postgres:1.0.1" in
Warning  FailedPostStartHook  25s (x2 over 41s)  kubelet            Exec lifecycle hook 
([/bin/sh -c /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sh]) for Container "app-postgres" inerror: code = ResourceExhausted desc = grpc: trying to send message larger than max (16959522 vs. 16777216), message: ""
```

I've tried to lessen the data that is being inserted and it works fine and the pod started successfully.

By the way, the file size of init_data_03.sql and init_data_04.sql is  around 23MB each.

I tried looking for some information regarding the error but I can't find any.

Comment: How did you solve this?